# SharePoint Crawl Progress Monitoring

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, crawling, crawl

Is there any way to monitor the progress (ideally in percent) of a (full) crawl in SharePoint?

Update:

I know I can monitor the progression by viewing the crawled items, but I want to find a way to have a real progress indicator, because having to do a full crawl on a large productive system with **no** indication of how long it might take and how much has already been done is basically unacceptable.

One very rough approach is to get the item count of the last crawl, track the current crawl's item count as mentioned and estimate progress by comparing those two.

Answer (score 0):

As far as in On-Premises you can click on Crawl History and check how many items successfully crawled in live under crawl diagnostics. (Even when crawl is running it will provide near-live updates).

But IMO, no facility to get percentage.

Reference: [Microsoft Crawl diagnostics](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219611.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I occasionally do that, but specifically for scripting it would be awesome... Is there a way to get the count of items to be crawled? Then one could manually create a progress calculation... otherwise one could get an estimate of progress by comparing the already crawled item count to the last crawls total count, but that will almost never be accurate ...

Comment: That is desired. agreed .you could raise this in user-voice.

Comment: I'd say that part of the point of crawling is to find out how many items there are in the system, thus having percentage of the progress is rather difficult to build. As @FatalMerlin mentioned it could be possible to compare to the results of previous crawl but as said it wouldn't be really that accurate.

Comment: It's not like SP could register and de-register an item when it's added or removed. Maybe it does so? I hope we can get some attention on the question, to draw in someone who might know :)